# How can I create a table with dynamic columns using asp.net controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, datamodel

Background: My data model is a `List<PersonDetail>`, where `PersonDetail` contains properties like `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc, and the List can be any size.

I want to create a table that can compare these `PersonDetails` side-by-side. This means for each column I need to take the data in a single `PersonDetail` and spread it across my 8 rows. Then do the same for the next `PersonDetail`.

I have a constraint where I can only use an Asp.Net control (`ListView`, `GridView`, `Repeater`, etc.) along with `control.DataSource` and `control.DataBind()` to create my table.

The template I want to do is something like:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate1>
  <td>
     <asp:Label ID="LabelFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
  </td>
</ItemTemplate1>

<ItemTemplate2>
  <td>
     <asp:Label ID="LabelLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
  </td> 
</ItemTemplate2>

<!-- and so on -->
```

Where the above `ItemTemplates` would be the only parts that repeat in the table.

I've tried all three control options and it doesn't seem to be supported without complicating the code-behind.

Is there a better data model I could use that can interface with another control? I've seen solutions like `DataTable`, but not sure if that will solve my problem..

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not wrap a Repeater with a `<table>` and create the `<tr>` in each `ItemTemplate`

Comment: The issue with that, if i'm not wrong, the Repeater would create a new set of 8 rows for each PersonDetail, and i'd end up with 1 column with 8 x Details.count number of rows.

Comment: You can create as many table rows and columns within the ItemTemplate as you want, there is no need to limit yourself to one `<td>`

Comment: My example above (multiple ItemTemplates) isn't supported in Asp.Net. If i Repeater a <tr> i'll end up appending the row to the bottom of the table, instead of adding a column

Comment: I've posted a simple example. You don't need a template for every property in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %></td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Street") %></td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try this approach, but i'm concerned i'll just get one column. We'll see.

Comment: I've switched to using a DataTable and a GridView with autogenerated columns. Thank you though!